# Putting all constants in one class android

Tags: java, android, class, constants

There are similar posts to mine but they date back to early 2010's so I'm not sure if things have changed.  I just got some code review back and the reviewer suggested I put all of my constants in one class and call them from there.  How can I do this and is this the right way to go? How do I declare and call them?

Comment: You don't know how to how to create a class? How to declare a field? Where *specifically* are you stuck?

Comment: It’s very opinion-based. IMHO: Declaring named constants is good. Putting all the constants in one place is bad. Instead put each constant in the class or interface where ot most naturally belongs. To make it more than opinion: A good design has low coupling and high cohesion. A class with all constants will have the opposite: coupling to many other classes and low to no internal cohesion.

Comment: Usage: You call methods. You don’t call constants. You just use them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whether it's "the right way" or not is mainly a matter of taste. There is no right or wrong here.

As to how to use them - simply have a class with a series of `public static final` fields:

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String FIRST_NAME = "Tarik";
    public static final String LAST_NAME = "Hodzic";
}
```

And then other classes can just use them:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public String getFullName() {
        return Constants.FIRST_NAME + " " + Constants.LAST_NAME;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's what enums are for.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

For example: you want to refer to a type in a certain category. The enum would be the category consisting of the many types.

Then whenever you want to use them it's just: category.typeN.

This is good because if the name of the type changes. Refactor it in the enum and it will change all of the "constants"

Comment: The price of ENUMs (100 Days of Google Dev) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzs6OBcvNQE
I suppose you will change your opinion after that video.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that. In my day to day applications they seem fine. But yeah, maybe not the best for Android apps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use annotations instead of constants now:

```
import android.support.annotation.IntDef;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.SOURCE;



@IntDef({
        TypeBodyItem.BODY_TYPE_UNKNOWN,
        TypeBodyItem.BODY_TYPE_HTML,
        TypeBodyItem.BODY_TYPE_ARTICLE,
        TypeBodyItem.BODY_TYPE_MEDIA,
})

@Retention(SOURCE)
public @interface TypeBodyItem {
    int BODY_TYPE_UNKNOWN = 0;
    int BODY_TYPE_HTML = 10;
    int BODY_TYPE_ARTICLE = 20;
    int BODY_TYPE_MEDIA = 30;
}
```

[An article](https://blog.reversebits.tech/miracle-stuff-in-android-intdef-and-stringdef-5aeab3c3f4f7) and [documentations](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations#enum-annotations) about annotations.

Answer (score 2):

The approach I use is this,

For any constants shared across the system (for example, REST endpoint URL), I will put it as final variables in a separate constants class.

For any constants specific to a component(Activity, Fragment etc.) I put it as a final variable in the component itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Make simple and easy constant class in android (Java) is here**

```
 public class Constants {
        /**
         * Object key prams when pass the json object from server.
         */
        public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
        public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
        public static final String KEY_DEVICE_TOKEN = "device_token";
        public static final String KEY_DEVICE_TYPE = "device_type";
        public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
        public static final String KEY_COUNTRY_CODE = "country_code";
        public static final String KEY_PHONE_CODE = "phone-code";
        public static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
        public static final String KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH = "date_of_birth";
        public static final String KEY_USER_ID = "user_id";
        public static final String KEY_LIMIT = "limit";
        public static final String KEY_DRIVER_ID = "driver_id";
        public static final String KEY_LONGTITUDE = "logitude";
        public static final String KEY_LATTITUDE = "lattitude";
        public static final String KEY_RATING = "rating";
        public static final String KEY_DETAILS = "details";
        public static final String KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN= "access_token";
        /**
         * Fragments name
         */
        public static final String FRAG_ETA = "ETA";
        public static final String FRAG_ACCOUNT_FRAGMENT = "ACCOUNT_FRAGMENT";
        public static final String FRAG_SETTING_FRAGMENT = "SETTING_FRAGMENT";
        public static final String FRAG_MAP_FRAGMENT = "MAP_FRAGMENT";
        public static final String FRAG_FEEDBACK = "FEEDBACK";
        public static final String FRAG_RATE_FRAGMENT = "RATE_FRAGMENT";
    
        public static final String USA_CODE = "+1";
    
        public static final String DISTANCE_SEARCH = "DISTANCE_SEARCH";
    
    
    }
```

Comment: its for the java

Comment: With Kotlin you don't need to declare a class. Just place your constants into a `Constants.kt` file like this: `const val KEY_DEVICE_TOKEN = "device_token"`